# MySQL Query to fetch the Xth details and degree

Tags: mysql

In my table (image below) there are 4 users are found. I want to Display who are complete X TH only But that users not complete Other course such as XII Th, Degree, and Post Graduate(**I need output from this table user_id 3 only**. Likewise I want to display who are complete Degree not Post graduate, in this table user_id 4 only complete Degree (**I need to output user_id 4 only complete degree**)). 
Please help me to find the solution. This is my query:

```
SELECT e.user_id
FROM tbl_educationalqualification e
WHERE e.user_mark >='36%' AND e.user_coursename ='X TH' AND
    e.user_coursename NOT IN ('XII TH','DEGREE','POST GRADUATE')**) ]
```

[image: table structure and sample data]

Comment: Show us your table structure with some sample data.

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401841/fetch-only-who-are-all-done-10th-only-not-12th-by-using-mysql/35401989#35401989

Comment: select t1.user_id from table1 t1 
where t1.mark ='50%' and t1.course_name ='X TH'